Why my binding in .NET Maui does not work?
1I am working on a .NET MAUI application that manages members and memberships. I am able to perform CRUD operations on members (add, delete, view, and update), and similarly, I can manage memberships as well (create, delete, view). However, I am facing an issue when trying to add a membership to a member. The problem occurs when I enter a member's details and expect to see a list of their associated memberships, but no memberships are displayed.
I have verified that there are no XAML binding failures, and there are no binding errors in the application. Everything seems to be fine from the binding point of view, but the membership list does not appear as expected after navigating to a member's details.
Expected Behavior:
When I select a member, I expect the list of memberships associated with that member to be displayed.
Actual Behavior:
The membership list is not displayed, even though I am able to create, update, and delete memberships for the member. However, after selecting a member, no memberships appear in the list.
I have made some research when i tried to debug in the GetMemberMembershipsAsync method. the count value shows as 0. This indicates that no data is being fetched from the database, even though I expect it to return results. So, no memberships are created.
This is the method that doesn't work:
````
    public Task<List<Membership>> GetMemberMembershipsAsync(int memberid)
{

    return _database.QueryAsync<Membership>(
"SELECT membership.ID, membership.MembershipName FROM Membership membership " +
"INNER JOIN Member M ON M.MembershipID = membership.ID " +  
"WHERE M.ID = ?", memberid);
    
    }
````

I will put the ListPage.xaml.cs
namespace MauiAppBazaSportiva;
using MauiAppBazaSportiva.Models;
public partial class ListPage : ContentPage
{
    public ListPage(Member member=null)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = member ?? new Member();
    }
    async void OnSaveButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var member = (Member)BindingContext;
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(member.FirstName)||string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(member.LastName))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Eroare", "Numele si prenumele sunt obligatorii", "OK");
            return;
        }
        await App.Database.SaveMemberAsync(member);

        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
    async void OnDeleteButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var member = (Member)BindingContext;
        await App.Database.DeleteMemberAsync(member);
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
    async void OnChooseButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var member = BindingContext as Member;

        if (member != null)
        {
            var membershipPage = new MembershipPage(new Membership());
            await Navigation.PushAsync(membershipPage);
            membershipPage.Disappearing += async (s, args) =>
            {
                if (membershipPage.SelectedMembership != null)
                {

                    member.MembershipID = membershipPage.SelectedMembership.ID;
                    await App.Database.SaveMemberAsync(member);
                    await DisplayAlert("Succes", "Abonamentul a fost asociat membrului.", "OK");
                    listView.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetMemberMembershipsAsync(member.MembershipID);
                }
            };
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "BindingContext nu este setat ca Membru.", "OK");
        }
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        if(BindingContext is Member member)
        {
            listView.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetMemberMembershipsAsync(member.ID);

        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "BindingContext nu e setat catre un membru", "OK");
        }
    }


}
    ````
    ````


using MauiAppBazaSportiva.Models;

namespace MauiAppBazaSportiva;

public partial class MembershipPage : ContentPage
{

    public Membership SelectedMembership { get; set; }
  public MembershipPage(Membership membership=null)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = membership ?? new Membership();
    }

    async void OnSaveButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (BindingContext is Membership membership)
        {
            await App.Database.SaveMembershipAsync(membership);

            listView.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetMembershipsAsync();
        }
        else
        {
         
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "BindingContext is not set to a Membership.", "OK");
        }
    }

    async void OnDeleteButtonClicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        var membership = listView.SelectedItem as Membership;
        await App.Database.DeleteMembershipAsync(membership);
        listView.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetMembershipsAsync();
    }
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        listView.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetMembershipsAsync();
    }
    async void OnAddButtonClicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        Membership m1;
        if(listView.SelectedItem is Membership selectedMembership)
        {

            var member = new Member()
            {
            };
            if(selectedMembership.Members==null)
            {
                selectedMembership.Members = new List<Member>();
            }
            await App.Database.SaveMemberAsync(member);
            selectedMembership.Members ??= new List<Member>();
            selectedMembership.Members.Add(member);
            await DisplayAlert("Succes", "Membru adaugat cu succes","OK");
            await Navigation.PopAsync();

        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Eroare", "Te rog selecteaza un abonament inainte de adaugarea membrului.", "OK");
        }
    }

}

I have included a link at the end of the post to the error image because I don’t have the reputation of 10 on Stack Overflow. As shown in the image, the subscription name is not appearing in the "Memberships" list, which indicates that the operation did not execute successfully. Despite trying various approaches, such as ensuring the correct relationships between the Member and Membership objects, the issue persists. This leads me to believe that the MembershipName is not being correctly fetched or displayed. I’m unsure what else to attempt or how to debug this issue effectively.

try assigning a HeightRequest value to the ListView

I tried but it didn't work.

var items  = await App.Database.GetMemberMembershipsAsync(member.ID);
var count = items.Count; if you put these in OnAppearing() and debug what is the value it shows for count?

I added and it shows 0

that means, your data is not getting fetched from DB.. so there will be no data shown in the listview

Do you know how could i solve the problem?

please i am stuck here i dont know what to do anymore

You need to use the debugger to step through your code

yeah but i dont know how to identify where the code is not working

i tried to debug but it doesnt work

"doesn't work" is not a helpful description of the problem.  If your count is 0, it stands to reason that the problem is in GetMemberMembershipsAsync so start there.  You have also not posted the code for that method.

Yeah you re right ,sorry.

@messi i don't think what you defined is a valid SQL query. I would recommend to use LINQ instead of using  query's

In several places you are calling GetMemberMembershipAsync without passing an ID parameter
